# How to list commits with no tags in Git

Tags: git

I want a list of all commits which do not have any tag associated with it, in a particular branch.

I tried

```
git show-ref --tags
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed!

Checkout branch then run `git log --format="%h %d" |grep -v '(tag:' | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: The earlier one kind of worked "git log l grep commit l grep -v '(tag:' "

Comment: It was close, but this is better

Comment: Current one is just printing all the commits in the branch.

Comment: Is that not what you want? It should only print commits without a tag.

Comment: It is just printing each and every commit in the branch.

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full, so I'll comment. I recommend removing the `(` before `tag` because if your tag is on the latest commit, the line looks like `<SHA>  (HEAD -> main, tag: v3.1.1, origin/main, origin/HEAD)` which won't match your current grep filter. New command: `git log --format="%h %d" | grep -v 'tag:' | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
git rev-list master |
    while read sha1; do
        test -z "`git tag --points-at $sha1`" &&
           git --no-pager show -s --format="%h %s" $sha1
    done
```

Let me explain:

```
git rev-list master
```

List SHA1 IDs of commits in the branch.

```
    while read sha1; do
```

Run a loop over every SHA1.

```
        test -z "`git tag --points-at $sha1`" &&
```

Test if there are no tags pointing to the commit.

```
            git --no-pager show -s --format="%h %s" $sha1
```

If there are no tags show abbreviated commit hash and the first line of
commit message.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-and-dirty solution for the current branch and assuming that your shell supports [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
git log --format='%H %d' |
  grep --fixed-strings --invert-match \
       --file=<(git for-each-ref --format='%(*objectname)' refs/tags)
```

In English, that reads “give me the hashes for commits reachable on the current branch except for those that are tagged.” Using `%(*objectname)` in the format gives the hash of the tagged commit rather than of the tag object itself, which allows us to subtract them from the `git log` output using `grep --invert-match` (a.k.a. `grep -v`).

Adding the decorate information (`%d`) to help orient the user does add some risk of spurious matches, but it is reduced by using the full SHA-1 object names.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --pretty="%D%H" --decorate=short --decorate-refs=refs/tags | grep -v "^tag: "
```

`--pretty="%D%H"` prints the ref and the hash.

`--decorate=short` prints the refs in the short format.

`--decorate-refs=refs/tags` prints only the tags.

`grep -v "^tag: "` excludes the lines starting with `tag:`. The rest are the commits that are not pointed at by any tag.